# How to crawl over all the webpages in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written this code. I want to get all the data from all the pages and store them in a CSV file. But I don't know what to do next. I can do this in beautifulsoup but it's not the same in selenium and beautifulsoup combination

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas

chrome_option = Options()
chrome_option.add_argument("--headless")


browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_option)

# list of data
names = []
license_num = []
types = []
contacts = []
links = []



def scrape(url):
    browser.get(url)
    sleep(5)
    html = browser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")

    sel_soup = bs(html, "html.parser")

    containers = sel_soup.find_all(class_ = "d-agent-card container_13WXz card_2AIgF")


    for cont in containers:
        # agent name
        agent = cont.find("h4").text.strip()
        names.append(agent)

        # agent type

        tp = cont.find("h5").text.strip()
        types.append(tp)

        # agent contact

        contact = cont.find("button", {"class": "button_3pYtF icon-left_1xpTg secondary_KT7Sy link_-iSRx contactLink_BgG5h"})
        if contact is not None:
            contacts.append(contact.text.strip())
        elif contact is None:
            contacts.append("None")

        # agent link

        link = cont.find("div", {"class": "linksContainer_1-v7q"}).find("a")

        if link is not None:
            links.append(link["href"])
        elif link is None:
            links.append("None")

        # license 

        licns = cont.find("p", {"class": "license_33m8Z"}).text
        license_num.append(licns)

for page in range(1, 27):
    urls = f"https://www.remax.com/real-estate-agents/Dallas-TX?page={page}"
    scrape(urls)


df = pandas.DataFrame({
    "Agent Name": names,
    "Agent Type" : types,
    "Agent License Number": license_num,
    "Agent contact Number": contacts,
    "Agent URL": links
    })
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

With this I am only getting 596 rows of data. But I want to get 24x25+ 19 = 619 rows. Every page has 24 rows of data. I want to get them. But I am only getting the data of 23 pages maybe. now I am getting an error ...

{"QTM: JSEvent:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined !!window.QuantumMetricAPI.lastXHR.data && !!JSON.parse(QuantumMetricAPI.lastXHR.data).term"}

Comment: a sample of desired output will be helpful though

Comment: I have edited my code. You can check where I am doing the mistake.

Comment: your question is really very duplicated question. the data presented within `script` tag. and even the entire site is saved in one `script` tag, also there's an `API`.

Comment: so, what should I do to extract all the data?